# Only Alphabet and whitespace allowed in UITextField Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to validate my textField that check only Alphabet & whitespace allowed, If number was given then it will return warning error.

```
//First I declare my value to variable
var nameValue: String = mainView.nameTextField.text!

//Then I declare this 
 let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")        

//And this is the validation
if(nameValue.rangeOfCharacter(from: set.inverted) != nil ){
    self.showAlert(message: "Must not contain Number in Name")
   } else {
      //other code
   }


ex: nameValue : "abcd" it works, but 
if nameValue : "ab cd" whitespace included, it returns the showAlert message.
```

This code works but only for alphabets, What I need now is alphabets and a whitespace. and what I declare was a hardcode I guess. Maybe you guys have better code and options for this case.

Thank you .

Comment: Which "alphabet"? Are "è", "Ä", "œ"  allowed as well? What about other languages (greek, arabic, chinese, hebrew, ...)? Did you have a look at the predefined characters sets (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset)?

Comment: no sir, only alphabet from a-z (Upper&Lower) @MartinR

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way will be to add new line to the character set like

```
let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ")
```

i.e, adding white space character at the end of the included character set" "

Rather than hardcoding you can use regular expression like

```
   do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z ].*", options: [])
    if regex.firstMatch(in: nameValue, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nameValue.characters.count)) != nil {
         self.showAlert(message: "Must not contain Number in Name")

    } else {

    }
}
catch {

}
```

Comment: this tricks works, but the code look like a hardcode, is there others way to declare this ?

Comment: I have edited the above answer and added more standard way other than hardcoding, please check and confirm if it works.

Comment: what strings refer to in this code `if regex.firstMatch(in: strings, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nameValue.characters.count)) != nil {
       `

Comment: oops I just copied the code I was trying on strings is actually the string or her in this case nameValue. I have edited the answer.

Comment: thanks man this code looks better than "hardcode" and it works well

Answer (score 15):

> `pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*"` its allow to enter characters, numbers,
> or space(" ")
>
> `pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z ].*"` its allow to enter characters, or space("
> ")
>
> `pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z].*"` its allow to enter only characters

Example below:

```
extension [YourViewController]: UITextFieldDelegate
{
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
                do {
                    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*", options: [])
                    if regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count)) != nil {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
            return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All the above solutions are fine but only work for English Alphabet `([^A-Za-z ])`. So this solution is not working for me because my app is developed for multiple language support. For this, I write a solution and this will work for all languages.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    let allowedCharacter = CharacterSet.letters
    let allowedCharacter1 = CharacterSet.whitespaces
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacter.isSuperset(of: characterSet) || allowedCharacter1.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> 1st you have to inherit the UITextFieldDelegate class with you own
>   class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

> 2nd add an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
```

> 3rd you have to assure this object is using

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   firstName.delegate = self
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == firstName {
                let allowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
                let typedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
                let alphabet = allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharacterSet)
                return alphabet


      } else {
        return false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use regex:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-zA-Z\\s]+", options: [])
```

You can match it like this:

```
let range = regex.rangeOfFirstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
return range.length == string.characters.count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    var lettersAndSpaces: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.union(.whitespaces).inverted).joined()
    }

   var isEmptyOrWhitespace: Bool {
    let whitespace = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
    return self.trimmingCharacters(in: whitespace).isEmpty
}
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
if newValue.lettersAndSpaces.isEmptyOrWhitespace {
 showError()
}
```

btw. This will also trigger on multiple "empty spaces" like

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition; Using a regex like this one: `[a-zA-Z\s]+` only works for ASCII alphabets and not unicode characters.

For example:

```
some string       -> Matches
some other string -> Matches
sömé øthër strīng -> NoMatches
test 漢字          -> NoMatches
```

If you want to match non ASCII alphabets as well, you might want to use: `[\p{L}\s]+` instead. `\p(L)` matches any kind of letter from any language.